# MongoDB Drop Database With Invalid Name

Tags: mongodb

I somehow ended up with a database named "*" on my mongo server.  I want to get rid of it, but I can't find a way to drop it.  Trying to execute the normal dropDatabase() functions don't work because the shell won't let me select it (i.e. I run "use *").

How can I drop this database?  I tried things like db.getSiblingDB("*").dropDatabase();

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I can drop it.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
connecting to: test
> use *
switched to db *
> db.test.insert({'t':1})    
> show tables    
system.indexes    
test
> show dbs;
*       0.203125GB
admin   0.203125GB
local   (empty)
> use *
switched to db *
> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "*", "ok" : 1 }
> show dbs;
admin   0.203125GB
local   (empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I had succeed switch to the database whose name contains "invalid" letters is to open the CMD in Windows and redirect to the mongodb /bin folder, and then open "mongo.exe" using command line with the database name u wanna switch to as the parameter. So here we go!

---

EX: Open database named "Congrès"

c:\Program Files\mongodb\bin>mongo.exe Congrès